# Constructing a weighting function with equal mean on two random variables

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I am not a mathematician, but I hope that it is understandable.
I try to tackle a problem which can be described as the following:

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random variables with same support $\Omega$ and their pdfs $p_1$ and $p_2$ being Gibbs distributions.

1. Under which conditions does there exist a weighting function $w: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $w(x) >0 \forall x \in \Omega$ and $w \not\equiv 1$ such that
   $$
   E\{w(X_1)\}=E\{w(X_2)\}
   $$
2. Is it possible to construct $w$ knowing $p_1$ and $p_2$?

//edit I clarrified the question after the first response as it was clearly underspecified that I am not including constant functions.

Comment: -1. Please do not modify the question after some answers are posted--especially if the modification is not signalled and if it makes said answer look irrelevant.

Comment: I thought I signalled it in the edit. But I see that this is not visible directly in the question. sorry for the confusion . I make it clear that I clarified the question. The old version was, given the comment, underspecified.

Comment: You did not "clarify", you modified. Once again, it is bad form to do so after an answer is posted.

Comment: I did as a quite long edit comment. I did not know that this was not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of weighing functions $w$ exist such that $E(w(X_1))=E(w(X_2))$, always. Try $w\equiv1$.

Comment: True, so existence is not an issue. However, even though these are plenty, I doubt that this is an exhaustive description of the class of functions.